# How to get average mssql connections of a server with Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

New to Prometheus/PromQL.

**Context**: I need to create a report that extracts multiple pieces of information from Prometheus and then send it to SharePoint in CSV format.

What's left it's to calculate the **average number of connections to a SQL Server instance over a 7-day period.**

I have no problem obtaining this metric at any given moment:

`(windows_mssql_genstats_logical_connections{nodename=~"xxxxx"})`
*473*

But how can I get a 7-day average, for example based on an everyday fixed-time sample?

My first deduction would have been to use something like this:

`avg(windows_mssql_genstats_logical_connections{nodename=~"xxxx"})[7d]`

Comment: To get an average value of the metric over 7 days, you should use `avg_over_time(...[7d])`